# Highlight text inside textarea like Facebook does

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I try to achieve something like the Facebook does when you type @<NAME_OF_A_FRIEND> in a reply. After you choose a friend, the name of that friend is highlighted with a blueish background, so you know it's a separate entity in that text.

I've "inspect element"-ed that textarea and there is no div placed on top of the textarea.

Can anyone give me a clue about how that is done ?

[image]

Comment: Facebook make the `textarea` transparent and put a `div` below. Try to inspect `textarea` element with Chrome and remove it, and try to find again the element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HR5N8/). I used only CSS and HTML... The JS is very more complex for now. I don't know exactly what you expect.

HTML:

```
<div id="textback">
    <div id="backmodel"></div>
</div>
<textarea id="textarea">Hey Nicolae, it is just a test!</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#textarea {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    font: 9pt Consolas;
}

#backmodel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 32px;
    background-color: #D8DFEA;
    width: 53px;
    height: 9pt;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I have a completely different approach to this issue using HTML5. I use a `div` with `contentEditable="true"` instead of a textarea (wich I was using until I got stuck with the same problem you had).

Then if I want to change the background color of a specified part I just wrapp that text with a span.

I am not 100% sure if it is the correct approach as I am a newbie in HTML5 but it works fine in all the browsers I have tested it (Firefox 15.0.1 , Chrome 22.0.1229.79 and IE8).

Hope it helps

Comment: Makes sense. But I (and apparently Facebook :P) prefer the more generic one :) Thank you nevertheless ;)

Comment: But the div doesn't increase in height automatically as you are typing in it . So as you go in typing text , doesn't it start to flow automatically. And then would need js to somehow increase the size of that...

Comment: Content editable attribute is supported for quite some time now, and it is adopted by most client-side color-highlight engines, here is an example for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/33588043/257319 (easier to understand and it use CSS and no inline-styles).

Answer (score 8):

The textarea has background-color: transparent; the extra div you're looking for is behind it, with the same text and font as the textarea, but different colours.

A short example to illustrate the point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<style>
* { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; }
.wrapper     { position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px; outline: solid 1px #666; }
.wrapper > * { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.highlighter { background-color: #fff; color: #fff; }
.highlight   { background-color: #9ff; color: #9ff; }
textarea     { background-color: transparent; border: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="highlighter">
This <span class="highlight">is a</span> demonstration.
</div>
<textarea>
This is a demonstration.
</textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, this does not update the special div as you type into the textarea, you need a lot of JavaScript for that.

Comment: +1 and thank you very much for your answer but I went with the David's answer because it's more straight forward to me.

Comment: You should never do it! absolute positioning and handling textual updates using javascript event-handlers on changes is not the best-practice, in-fact due to the amount of time and effort required to provide and maintain a cross-browser working solution- should be render this answer as plain-harmful!

Comment: @EladKarako I attempted to answer with the info on what Facebook does -- or did at the time -- which was what was asked in the question. I neither recommend this approach nor recommend any alternative, since I have not had any reason so far for comparing the different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

hi you can check this jquery autosuggest plugin similar to facebook .I have used this to achive the same functionality you required
http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/

Comment: Thank you! Looks awesome. Actually, I'm looking for something like this for iPhone, but rather more complicated.

Answer (score -5):

I would suggest changing the text you want to assign a background inline to to `display: inline-block; background-color: #YOURCOLOR;`. This should do exactly what you want it to do without all the complexities of some of the above answers.

Ultimately your CSS should look something like this:

```
.name {display: inline-block; background-color: purple;}
```

Then add some sort of event listener in jQuery (not sure how you're identifying that it is a name) and inside that conditional put:

```
$(yourNameSelectorGoesHere).addClass(".name");
```

Comment: You didn't answer my question (or so I believe): how can I change the style to a part of the text inside a textarea?

Comment: The current answer provided does not work. It is not flexible at all. You have to use javascript to listen. I cannot give you an example of an event listener because I do not know enough about what exactly you are looking for. But what I'm doing in my code example is adding a class to a name and giving it a background color. You can only do this if are listening for a name. Once a name is identified simply add a class to it's DOM element that does what you want it to do. Absolutely positioning a div behind it is not workable a solution.

Comment: I know how to use jQuery. You can't just put elements inside a textarea, only text.

Comment: Believe it or not, absolutely positioning a div behind the textarea is exactly what Facebook does. @Nicolae is right - you cannot put elements inside a textarea, so this is one of the only ways to do it.